# How to derive $P(Y=y_{i}|X) = \frac{P(X=x_k|Y=y_i)P(Y=y_i)}{\sum_{j}P(X=x_k|Y=u_j)P(Y=y_j)}$

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

I am reading a [material](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/NBayesLogReg.pdf) related to *Naive Bayes Algorithm*.

Assume that $Y$ is a boolean-valued random variable, and $X$ is a vector containing n boolean attributes. It claimes that $P(Y=y_{i}|X)$ can be represented as

$$\frac{P(X=x_k|Y=y_i)P(Y=y_i)}{\sum_{j}P(X=x_k|Y=y_j)P(Y=y_j)}$$

I think Bayes rule is involved here. But why $P(Y=y_{i}|X)$ is not represented as

$$\frac{P(X|Y=y_i)P(Y=y_i)}{P(X)}$$

I am particularly confused about the denominator.

I think the subscript $j$ denotes all possible values of $Y$.

Comment: It is, but then you have to find $P(X)$, which is ${\sum_{j}P(X=x_k\mid Y=y_j)P(Y=y_j)}$

Comment: Here $y_j$ are all the possible values of $Y$, assuming they are indexable, i.e. $Y$ is a discrete distribution.  If not, if $Y$ were a continuous random variable, you might have to use integration rather than summation

Comment: @Henry. Why $P(X)$ is that? I guess it is some basic rules in statistics. Can you explaint that or point me to the some references?

Comment: $P(X)$ $=P\left(X \cap \left(\bigcup_j Y=y_j\right)\right)$ $=P\left(\bigcup_j \left(X \cap Y=y_j\right)\right)$ $= \sum_j P\left(X \cap Y=y_j\right) $ $= \sum_j P\left(X \mid Y=y_j\right) P\left(Y=y_j\right)  $

Comment: @Henry that's a bit too complicated for me (sorry). Any keyword I can search in Google so that I can learn that on my own?

Comment: It is just conditional probability combined with saying the probability of $X$ is the sum of the probabilities of $X$ and each possible $Y$

Comment: @Henry it seems that this wiki page explains the issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ideas used here.  One is Bayes' rule, as you already know.  For two events $A, B$, we have $$\Pr[A \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[B \mid A]\Pr[A]}{\Pr[B]}.$$  The second idea is the law of total probability, namely $$\Pr[A] = \Pr[A \mid B]\Pr[B] + \Pr[A \mid \bar B]\Pr[\bar B],$$ where $\bar B$ is the complementary event of $B$ (so in particular, $\Pr[B \cap \bar B] = 0$ and $\Pr[B] + \Pr[\bar B] = 1$).

The law of total probability naturally extends to the case where we have a set of outcomes that partition the sample space, and where one has a discrete-valued random variable $Y$ with support $Y \in \{y_0, y_1, \ldots \}$, we have $$\Pr[A] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \Pr[A \mid Y = y_i]\Pr[Y = y_i].$$